# Proof: $\cot(7.5^\circ) = \sqrt2 +\sqrt3 + \sqrt 4 + \sqrt6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, radicals, fractions, number-comparison

I am working on this problem, but I am not able to simplify the expression.

So please help me. 
Thanks in advance